# How to distinguish between different XML properties with same name?

Tags: xml, parsing, properties, xml-parsing

Let's say we have the following XML sturcture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <prefix>git</prefix>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${artifactId}_git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    <format>json</format>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am seeing that reference to `artifactId` in following line, resolves to **ProjectName**(first artifactId in the file) and not **git-commit-id-plugin**(second artifactId in the file).

`<generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${artifactId}_git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>`

How does XML parser resolve references to a property that exists more than once (at different levels) ? Does it resolve to the property with same name at **highest level** (assuming root to be the highest level) **that can be found** before the current level ?

Comment: some libraries manage this with nodes.

Comment: A XML parser does not resolver the tree structure of the data.  The user has to make sure the path to the property is unique.  When duplicate occur you have parse in pieces to unique node(s) to get any specific child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML parser... well... parses. It has nothing to do with interpretation of xml content. It's up to a consumer of xml (an author of a program that needs that xml) what to make of strings like `"${project.build.outputDirectory}/${artifactId}_git.properties"`. And that IS just a string. The XML parser has no notion of its meaning. And as for the consumer, as far as it goes, he can replace `artifactId` with anything he likes. It may be `project.artifactId`. It may be `project.build.plugins.plugin.artifactId`. Or it may even be something as strange as a poem. So... you can never know until you read a documentation for that particular xml configuration file.

PS. And then... there is XSLT. But it's a different story. Yet the same output - you never know what a result would be until you read XSLT-code or some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The document claims conformance to the schema at http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd, so to find out the meaning of the element called artifactId you need to look in that schema. The XML parser itself ignores the schema, but if you perform schema validation (which may be done in the course of XML parsing, or separately), then the schema validator will take account of any constraints imposed by the schema, which might, for example, say that the content of one element is a reference to the name of another.

In this case, however, the schema defines artefactId simply as a string. So the meaning of this string depends solely on the application processing the XML, taking account of any explicit or implicit agreements made between the sender and the recipient of the XML as to how the field is to be used.